# Nginx not serving CRA static files properly

Tags: nginx

Following the [Nginx's Serving Static Folder](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/?_bt=569765980296&_bk=&_bm=&_bn=g&_bg=130682555189&gclid=CjwKCAjwrqqSBhBbEiwAlQeqGu9_tcO13bEmEsAan3onNeow34vUwIfsLPRkobNxaGVruQmW0nbLyBoC6OYQAvD_BwE) I was able to serve my [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/) in the web server. However, All JS and CSS are getting 404 errors due to my app is pointing out a different static path, that's why I added a different static folder for assets, but it is failing.

[image]

This is my server block code:

```
  location /panel {                                                                                                        
    alias /var/www/puebla-checkout/client/build/;                                                                         
  }                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                
  location /static {                                                                                                       
    alias /var/www/puebla-checkout/client/build/static/;                                                                   
  }
```

`/panel` works well serving index and images.

This is the folders/structure of the project:

[image]

What's wrong in my code? Why I can't serve css and js files?

Comment: What happens if you remove these 2 location blocks and instead use `location / { root /var/www/puebla-checkout/client; }` ?

Comment: It's not an option in this case, I'm using Location / for server_proxy, e.g `location /  { proxy_pass    http://localhost:5000;`

Comment: If `localhost:5000` is your REST API - my suggestion is to switch their roles, i.e. proxying `/api` to your REST API and leaving the static files under `/` location.